# Can we merge [android-tabs] and [android-tablayout]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Can we merge these tags? Both are being used for [**`TabLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout).

Questions tagged [android-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-tabs): 1,200.
Questions tagged [android-tablayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-tablayout): 1,532.

Comment: Looks like a straightforward request to me. Can't you suggest [tag:android-tabs] as a synonym [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-tablayout/synonyms), though?

Comment: Bleh, I realise I responded and went to go into action on this post having totally misread it 3 times.  Hope I didn't cause confusion, I reverted my damage

Comment: 75 questions tagged with both: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-tabs+android-tablayout

Comment: @Cœur yes your are right but when check the question of [android-tabs] all question is about  `TabLayout`  i have also checked  the [top user](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-tabs/topusers) of  [android-tabs] tag and same result I.e.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640563), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892545), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486100)

Comment: @NileshRathod I've updated my answer in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, [android-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-tabs) is vague and may refer to at least two UI element: [android-tablayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-tablayout) and [android-tabhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-tabhost).

So my previous opinion on making them synonyms may be a mistake. It may be best to re-tag manually.

---

<s>Indeed, both tags cover the same Android UI element.</s>

<s>I concur with TylerH comment, we should make [android-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-tabs) a synonym of the explicit [android-tablayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-tablayout).</s>

<s>If you have 5 points in the tag (or if you're a moderator), you can vote for it on https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-tablayout/synonyms.</s>

Comment: There are many more tab solutions in Android than `TabLayout`, and I expect that many of the older `android-tabs` questions will not be about `TabLayout`.

Comment: @CommonsWare after investigating old questions, you seem right.